# i have to print the directory of main directory, error is: FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified:

Tags: python, list

```
ftp_Home = 'C://Users//xyz//abc'
dir_main = os.listdir(ftp_Home)
for i in dir_main:

    abc = os.getcwd()
    dir_list = os.path.join(abc,i)
    ms = os.chdir(dir_list)
    print(ms)
```

As i have to print the list from the output of dir-main, e.g 'C://Users//xyz//abc///mno'

Comment: welcome to SO. it's a bit difficult to determine what you want. maybe look at `os.walk()`.

Comment: I want a list of folders inside the dir_list,

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are confusing forward and backward slashes. Windows uses `\`backslashes to delineate folders, and since that is an escape character, you need to escape the escape character to tell python you just want a single backslash, like this: `\\`. You are using forward slashes `/`, which is not the correct symbol for windows, and trying to escape them, even though they don't need escaping.

Try this, instead:

```py
ftp_Home = 'C:\\Users\\xyz\\abc'
```

Comment: ftp_Home = 'C:\\Users\\xyz\\abc\\FTPHome\\'
dir_main = os.listdir(ftp_Home)
for i in dir_main:
    print("In Loop i:",i)
    abc = os.getcwd()
    dir_list = os.path.join(abc,i)
    #print(dir_list)
    ab = os.chdir(dir_list)
    print(ab)

Comment: actually i want to print 1 more list which comes the inside the dir_list

Comment: @DeepKandpal can you elaborate?

Comment: actually i get the directories of abc, then i iterate the list with "for i in dir_main:" and inside that loop i concatenate the directory and list outcome(...//xyz//abc//mno) now i want list after that... like (...//xyz//abc//mno//pqr).